# redirect all files to index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I try to redirect all files and folders to `index.php` for an MVC routing but it working only from `index.php` like `learn.delapiata.ro/index.php/i/can/put/anything/here/and/redirect`

I wish to work without `index.php`: `learn.delapiata.ro/controllers/any_php_file.php`

I am using this in `.htaccess`:

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

What you have would already work - but you only need the `-f` rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule  ^ index.php [L]
```

These rules simply mean: If the request does not point at a file that exists - send the requeset to `index.php`

Note that htaccess files only take effect *at all* if they are enabled in the apache config. If for example the htaccess file is modified to contain an error (put "asdf" in it) - and you don't get a 500 response - Apache isn't reading the .htaccess files and this is why it "doesn't work". To fix that, put [AllowOverride All](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) somewhere appropriate in your apache config file and restart apache.

Comment: Thank you AD7six.
I already have the file rule:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

Comment: I have try and I have AllowOverride All in apache but it doesn't work

Comment: This work:
http://learn.delapiata.ro/index.php/test/file.php
But this do not work:
http://learn.delapiata.ro/test/file.php

Comment: Read my advice in the answer, determine if your .htaccess file is doing anything at all and go from there. The fact that you get an apache 404 should indicate that you do not have mod rewrite enabled.

Comment: Out of interest where does your .htaccess file come from? For example why do you have a rewrite base (not ordinarily required, and not for "/"), permit folder listings and disable symlinks?

Comment: Thank you AD7  I add path to directory in apaceh and now it working :
<Directory  /var/www/learn/public_html/>
 #enable the .htaccess rewrites
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Allow from All
</Directory>